# Error con Variable PHP indefinida en un sitio donde si esta indefinida

Tags: php, php7, variables-globales

chicos poseo un proyecto PHP donde tengo un archivo con las function que se deben ejecutar, en este miso archivo poseo declaracion de las variables globales una de estas variables es:
`$usua         = $_SESSION['user']['username'];`
Esta variable la uso mucho dentro de otras function donde ya los usuarios se han logeado en el sistema, pero no la uso en las function para la recuperacion de claves de acceso, el error que me da es el de variable indefinida, quisiera saber si me pueden orientar indicando como puedo dar instrucciones a mi codigo para que cuando no este definida la variable esta sea omitida, o se le asigne el valor 0 o null. intente con un `if (!$usua)`pero entonces en las function donde requiero el valor de esta variable con el llamado de `global $usua` no funciona indicando que la variable es nula, otras veces dice que esta indefinida etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de [isset](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) para determinar si la variable existe. Por ejemplo:

```
// Si la variable existe se retorna TRUE y el texto se imprimirá.
if (isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])) {
    echo "Esta variable está definida, así que se imprimirá";
}
```

Ahora podemos llevar esto a la asignación del valor dependiendo de su existencia.Una opción podría ser lo siguiente:

```
$usua = isset($_SESSION['user']['username']) ? isset($_SESSION['user']['username']) : 0;
```

En el anterior codigo lo que estamos haciendo es verificar si existe, en el caso de que retorne "true" le asigna el valor que contiene. En caso contrario se asigna el valor 0 (cero).

Espero que te sea útil. Saludos!